# Как ограничить область перетаскивания QGraphicsItem внутри QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, mouse-event, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

я создаю небольшое приложение на Qt/C++ для работы с графическими элементами: оно представляет собой прямоугольную область, где можно перетаскивать объекты с помощью мыши, и вращать вокруг своей оси при помощи отдельного интерфейса.

Для того, чтобы объекты можно было перетаскивать мышью, при добавлении их на сцену, я устанавливаю флаг: `setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable)` и это работает очень качественно.

В качестве контейнера для множества перемещаемых объектов выступает QGraphicsScene.

Но есть одна единственная проблема, которую я не могу решить - объект внутри сцены можно перетаскивать бесконечно далеко за пределы видимой области. `setSceneRect()` не помогает. Также я пробовал переопределять методы `mousePressEvent()` и `mouseMoveEvent()` и внутри них ограничивать перемещение, но тут проблема в том, что я теряю преимущества использования флага `setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable)`. Например при использовании флага, когда поворот объекта (вокруг своей оси) ненулевой его захват и перемещение работают все также корректно, а при переопределении мне так и не удалось нормально реализовать эти две функции. Также ограничение его перемещения по сцене при повороте объекта, работает очень криво.

Мне кажется очень странным то, что в Qt есть возможность использовать уже готовый функционал для перетаскивания объектов на сцене, но чтобы ограничить эту самую сцену, нужно переписывать весь этот функционал заново, хотя требование об ограничении сцены очень очевидное и нужное...

Поэтому возник вопрос - можно ли как-то ограничить область перетаскивания графических объектов внутри QGraphicsScene, и при этом сохранить использование флага `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable`.

Comment: вы наверное можете включить флаг `QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges`, но тогда я думаю придётся делать свои `QGraphicsItem` путём переопределения `QGraphicsItem::itemChange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим размер сцены **800x600**.

P.S. размеры объекта сами высчитаете и досчитаете до центра.

**Класс объекта от QGraphicsItem:**

-добавь флаг на передвижение в конструктор

-добавь **2** переменные, куда сохраняешь позиции **int oldX, oldY;**

-добавь функции проверки выхода за границы сцены

```
bool observer_ward(int oldX, int oldY){
    if(oldX <= 800 && oldX >= 0 && oldY <= 600 && oldY >= 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

-добавь **mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneEvent* event)**

```
void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneEvent* event){
    QPointF point = mapToScene(event->pos());
    if(observer_ward(point.x(), point.y())){//если не выходим за границы, то сохраняем каждую новую валидную в наши переменные
        oldX = point.x();
        oldY = point.y();
    }
    else{//если вышли за границы, то возвращаемся в последнюю валидную
        this->setPos(oldX, oldY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно залезть внутрь Qt и к флагу добавить ограничение, но это тоже самое как выключить ASSERT'ы внутри Qt, чтобы при работе с пустыми контейнерами не падать - поэтому ограничитесь своим кодом и внутрь Qt лезть - плохой стиль